# Bash - How do I pass in parameters using an array?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am trying to run a program with many parameters as follows:

```
./some-program -c 1 -c 2 -c 3 ...
```

How should I create such a command in Bash shell scripting?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an array of arguments:

```
args=(-c 1 -c 2 -c 3)
./some-program "${args[@]}"
```

You could also add the command to the array:

```
args=(./some-program -c 1 -c 2 -c 3)
"${args[@]}"
```

Or if you add your parameters one after another, you could do something like

```
args=()
args+=(-c)
args+=(1)
args+=(-c 2)
args+=(-c 3)
./some-program "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: My favorite syntax is `cmd=(\newline code \newline)`, since whitespace is effectively ignored, and i cant separate options and values etc with newlines, optionally with comments above.

Comment: yes very useful with things like `find` and `rsync` which take many arguments.